# Importing data from files to database by the users of the site

Tags: php, mysql, message-queue

It's necessary to allow users to import their data on the site (in mysql database). Every user who logs in, can import data from a file to the database and then work with them on the site. It takes a long time to import the data and creates a high load on the database as well.
Could you please tell how to queue importing better? So the data would be imported at one online, but to queue data to be written periodically to the database. 
Thank you.

Comment: How are you handling it currently?  Are your data imports XML, CSV?

Comment: You could try storing the files into a directory, adding them to a queuing database, and then have a process run periodically grabbing the next queued item.

Comment: Data from .csv file are not written to one database, but in several  related table. So to import data it's necessary to read a line from file and form a several sql statements that has to write data, it looks like INSERT INTO main_tabel; LASTINSERTID(); Insert for this id into related tables.

Comment: I import now from .csv and after user clicks import button I start this long operation online, which is not very good.

Comment: Eeach file contains much data and importing data from it takes much time.

Comment: Perhaps it's possible to store file in the queuing database and making delays between importing a port of data from the file. There are some questions about it too: 1. Would zend_queue be ok for such tasks using database? <br />  2. Should I create a cli php script to lauch by cron? <br /> 3. What is the best practices of using tasks like this to make it rather reliable? <br /> 4. Would it be ok isf the script would work in a loop all the time in the system, checking if there is data to import and if there is import them by small portions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to upload the .CSV file and post a message into a queue (or post the message on some other event like click on "Import" button). This way you will be able to return immediately and display a message like "Please wait for import". Then once the import is done and the database is updated the HTML page can refresh itself and display proper status. Depending on the servers and/or database load you can have only one or multiple simultaneous imports going on at the same time.

Comment: Yes, but is it worth using scripts in cli php for cron that will process importing in this case? I'd like to import file by small portion and at the same time to import without logn delays as far as it's possible. I wonder how to make it better in script that imports data periodically? I use Zend Framework and it's rather interesting if Zend_Queue is ok for such task (it seems to me it needs another connection to database for it, thought I'm not quite sure about it now).

Comment: based on the queue manager that you use you could set it up so that the queue manager starts the client when there is a new message in the queue (i.e. there will be no delay before processing).
I am not sure if Zend_Queue is capable of doing this kind of processing.

Comment: I don't think Zend_Queue  can do it.

Comment: After uploading a file there is also a page that maps data in .csv to fields in the system, this info must be also store in the queue I suppose.

Comment: Yes, you can make it part of the message for the processing of the specific uploaded .CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [insert delayed](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-delayed.html) would help.  From the manual:

> Another major benefit of using INSERT
>   DELAYED is that inserts from many
>   clients are bundled together and
>   written in one block. This is much
>   faster than performing many separate
>   inserts.

Comment: Maybe I'll process small files online, but larger fiels needs some queue mechanism.